# json into html table with conditions

Tags: html, json

```html
    @if(@Model.Count != 0)
        {
            <table class="body-Container">
                @foreach (var obj in Model)
                {
                    if (@obj.Name == "Free")
                    {
                        <tr class="accordionFree">
                            <td><a> </a></td>
                            <td><a>@obj.Name</a></td>
                            <td><a>@obj.Hour</a></td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (obj.Pay == false)
                        {
                            <tr class="accordionF">
                                <td><a>Not Pay</a></td>
                                <td><a>@obj.Name</a></td>
                                <td><a>@obj.Hour</a></td>
                            </tr>
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            <tr class="accordionT">
                                <td><a>Pay</a></td>
                                <td><a>@obj.Name</a></td>
                                <td><a>@obj.Hour</a></td>
                            </tr>
                        }
                    }
                }
            </table>
        }
        else
        {

        <a style="color:#555">Eror</a>
        }
```

I have html page that I get a list of model without json and I parsing him into table with if and else ,I'm trying to change the code because now I get JSON How do I enter the List that I get from JSON into the table with these conditions?
Each class is a different design

Comment: That doesn't look like html at all, it looks more like ASP.NET MVC Razor syntax. Can you provide more details? You'll only get half an answer for half a question...

Comment: Deserialize your JSON into your list of model and the use this model in the syntax.

Comment: is this is my View in mvc , I send list of model and presents him into table with if and else,  I want to change it because I was change my code and now I get JSON but I don't know how to presents him into table with if and else שs I did there